# How to see files which contain space in their names in one row?

Tags: bash, shell, parsing, whitespace, ls

When I set a name for a file like "project report.pdf" and list it via a for loop and $@ method, I see the name of the file separately like "project" in one row and "report.pdf" in another row. How can I see this file in one row? I need an output like "project report.pdf" after the code that I mentioned. What should I do?

```
set $(ls)
for i in $@
do
echo $i;
done
```

Output of this code:

```
project
report pdf
```

Comment: Why not `for f in *; do echo "$f"; done`??

Comment: It solved my problem. Thanks a lot!

Comment: [Why *not* parse `ls`?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls)

Comment: And also, use more quotes: `echo "$i"`, and use `"$i"` each time, **with the quotes around** `$i`: for example, `rm "$i"`, **and not** `rm $i`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ls` is [useless](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#ls)  You can do this simply with

```
printf '%s\n' *
```

More generally, see [When to wrap quotes around a shell variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable)